# What does individual variables mean ? Can be propositional variables?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> We know that any particular **first-order language** is 
>   determined by its symbols. These consist of ;
>
> $ 1-) \ $ A denumerable list of symbols called individual variables.
>
> - A denumerable list of symbols $(\text{not in }1)$ called individual parameters.
> - the connectives ; $\land ,\lor ,\lnot , \rightarrow $
> - for each natural number $n$, a set of $n$-ary relation symbols (also 
>     called predicate symbols).
> - for each natural number $n$, a set of $n$-ary function symbols.
> - the quantifiers ; $ \forall , \exists$
> - parentheses and the comma. $( \ , \ )$

---

My qeustion :

$1-) \ $ What does  **individual variables** mean ? Can be **propositional variables**?

$2-) \ $ In first-order language ; Can be definition symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What does *individual variable* mean ?

It is a *term*, i.e. a symbol that acts as a name for an object.

Thus, it cannot be a propositional variables, i.e. a symbols that stands for a sentence.

Consider the simple example from first-order language of arithmetic : $(x=0)$.

In this formula $x$ must be replaced by  a number in order to give an arithmetical meaning to the formula.

---

> 2)  In first-order language, can be definition symbol ?

A definition must either introduce a *term*, i.e. a symbol acting as a name for an object, or a *predicate* letter, i.e. a symbol naming a property.

Again, examples from [first order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) : we start from the basic symbols of the language : $0$ (an *individual constant* denoting the number $\text {zero}$), the unary *function* $s(x)$ (the $\text {successor}$ function) and the binary function $+(x,y)$ (the $\text {sum}$ operation, abbreviated with : $(x+y)$).

With them we define the new constant $1$ as $s(0)$.

And we define the new binary predicate $<(n,m)$ (the relation $\text {less than}$, abbreviated with $(n < m)$) as follows :

> $(n < m) \text { iff } \exists z \ (m=n+s(z))$.